# How to call a twig filter dynamically

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to render data with unknown type with filters that specific on each data type:

the rendered structures looks like:

```
array(
    "value"  => "value-to-render",
    "filter" => "filter-to-apply",
)

{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.value|item.filter|raw}}
{% endfor %}
```

So **My Question is**: How can I get twig to use item.filter as a filter on the value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to write your filter, which will call filters by passing name to it.

How to initially write you Extension you can read [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

Assuming that you have created you extension, you have define your custom function, (e.g., `customFilter`).

```
//YourTwigFilterExtension.php

public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        ...
        'custom_filter' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'customFilter'),
    );
}
```

Then, you have to define this function

```
public function customFilter($context, $filterName)
{
    // handle parameters here, by calling the 
    // appropriate filter and pass $context there
}
```

After this manipulations you'll be able to call in Twig:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ custom_filter(item.value, item.filter)|raw  }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, if you've defined your filter as filter (not as function):

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.value|custom_filter(item.filter)|raw  }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Applying the filter didn't work this way, but it worked:

`{{ item.value|apply_filter(item.filter)|raw }}`

Comment: I guess, because you have defined it as filter, not as function (as I described). In this case, `item.value` is passed into your filter as `$context` automatically :)

Comment: how did you call filter from CustomFilter ? How to call twig extension from PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

This Twig extension did the trick for me:

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace\YourBundle\Twig;

use \Twig_Extension;
use \Twig_SimpleFilter;
use \Twig_Environment;

class ApplyFilterExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'apply_filter_twig_extension';
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('apply_filter', array($this, 'applyFilter'), [
                    'needs_environment' => true,
                ]
            ));
    }

    public function applyFilter(Twig_Environment $env, $value, $filterName)
    {
        $twigFilter = $env->getFilter($filterName);

        if (!$twigFilter) {
            return $value;
        }

        return call_user_func($twigFilter->getCallable(), $value);
    }
}
```

And then in your template:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.value|apply_filter(item.filter)|raw}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is directly linked to one of my questions :

[Show variable inside variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314625/show-variable-inside-variable)

The answer is that you need a kind of "eval" method that doen't exist yet(but soon). BUT you also can create your own function as @thecatontheflat mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a Symfony Bundle for that:

Take a look here: https://github.com/marcj/twig-apply_filter-bundle

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension to dossorio's answer that allows chaining multiple filters as well as passing extra parameters to filters when needed:

```
class applyFiltersExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'apply_filters_twig_extension';
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('apply_filters', [$this, 'applyFilters'], [
                    'needs_environment' => true,
                ]
            )];
    }

    public function applyFilters(Twig_Environment $env, $value, array $filters = null)
    {
        if (empty($filters)) {
            return $value;
        }

        foreach ($filters as $filter) {
            if (is_array($filter)) {
                $filter_name = array_shift($filter);
                $params      = array_merge([$env, $value], $filter);
            } else {
                $filter_name = $filter;
                $params      = [$env, $value];
            }
            $twigFilter = $env->getFilter($filter_name);
            if (empty($twigFilter)) {
                continue;
            }

            $value = call_user_func_array($twigFilter->getCallable(), $params);
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

.