# Execute a twig variable inside another twig variable

Tags: symfony, session-variables, twig

I'm working on a symfony2 project. In a file `html.twig` i have the following code: `{{ app.session.get('menu') | raw }}` that refers to a field in a database table contained in a session. The value of this field is :

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<a class="brand" href="#">Menu1</a>
<ul class="nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ path('graphe') | raw}}">Graphe</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Now at this point the menu is displayed perfectly, but when i click on "Graphe", i get the error `No route found for GET /{{ path('graphe') | raw}}` which means that the code is not executed but taken as a string instead.
Is there any other way it can be executed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to remove the raw ? You don't need it when you use the path method. And why did you put your menu in session? Why didn't you just create a twig with your menu inside and just include it whenever you need it? Have a look on http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages could help you

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945200/twig-variables-in-twig-variable maybe it will help.

Comment: Well the reason behind putting the menu inside a session, is that every user should has his own menu, so when he connects the session gets its code. As for the raw yes i tried to remove it but the problem seems to persist.

Comment: Well if the menu is different between users you can generate it from a php function and then just inject it in the twig, anyway does graphe is a route that is registered in your routing.yml ? Did you try with another route?

Comment: yes the route exists in the routing.yml file, actually what i want to do is to have a menu in a html.twig file from which other files can inherit, that's why i thought about the session ... Well if there is any other solution i'm all ears. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

what you need is an eval like function because for now, twig interpret variable as simple text.

to summarize, you need to write your own filter to interpret variable.

Full answer here : [How to call a twig filter dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130540/how-to-call-a-twig-filter-dynamically/12140997#12140997)

Answer (score 0):

In your twig template embed a controller which renders your user menu. For more info see:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers