# Symfony2: A menu that depends of the user

Tags: html, session, symfony, twig

When a user logs in and during his navigation through the website, the navigation bar contains his menu (every user has his own menu). To do so i proceeded this way: first i put inside a database's table a field containing the html code that belongs to each user, then when a user connects this field is put inside a session and displayed in a twig file called admin.html.twig like this:

```
{{ app.session.get('menu')}}
```

And every page the user accesses automatically inherits from this page Admin.
Well, my solution doesn't seem to work, I've been told that i have to think about filters something like this, but i didn't really get how this solution. 
I know that something is wrong with my logic, any hints ? ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Example of what a menu contains:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Menu1</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path('graphe'|url_encode())}}">Graphe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Administration <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="gest_utilisateur">Gestion des utilisateurs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gestion des Menus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gest_domaine">Gestion des Domaines</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gest_equipe">Gestion des Equipes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea to me. There shouldn't be any reason for a User (Model layer) to contain information about a menu (View layer). What is in each user's menu? Is it the same for each user?

Comment: no each user has his own menu. yep i'm aware of how bad my idea is.

Comment: I'm trying to help you here but you didn't answer my question...what is in each user's menu? What makes it "his own"? Do they actually provide the HTML for it or do they just configure it somehow?

Comment: Well when i create a user i accord a menu to him depending on what's he is going to do. Actually the website is created for workers each one has different functionality that's why after talking to them i created for every one of them his own menu.

Answer (score 0):

I will do this in that way:

1. Add menu field to User Entity
2. In the template i will get this by:

   ```
   {{ app.user.getMenu() }}
   ```

   Because the user is also stored in the session.

Comment: Well it didn't work, actually i posted the same thing or what i thought my problem was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687382/execute-a-twig-variable-inside-another-twig-variable

Comment: Instead of html in the db I will rather keep an instance of the KNPMenuBundle menu serialized to json by JMSerializerBundle service.